# How to show wml pages on android phone

Tags: android

I want to show wml page on android. I have designed small wml page. I am using Apache  server to deploy the pages. But the page is not displaying. It is displaying just like xml page. I have added some line to mime.types which is given in following site 
http://e-articles.info/e/a/title/How-To-Configure-Apache-or-IIS-Web-Server-to-Work-with-WML-~-Openwave-SDK/

Still it is not working on android emulator...  any idea??

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Android's edition of WebKit does not support WML. It is possible you can find some third-party WML app.

Answer (score 1):

Im having a similar issue. I just finished our new website using WordPress. The site comes up but in XML format. The WordPress theme didn't load nor did any pictures. I used WordPress and a similar template to create another site and that is coming up fine. The only thing I can think of I did 301 redirects and maybe that is effecting the new site's display on Android devices.